# what is the difference between destroy and free and close

Tags: delphi

I am learning Delphi recently but when I want to close a dialog or a form, It works with Close and Free and Destroy commands.

What is the difference between these commands and how should I decide which one to use?

Comment: What does the [manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.TObject.Free) say?

Comment: [Form.Close manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Close)

Comment: A bit open ended this one. Between Free and Destroy you typically use Free because it is nil reference safe. Not important here I guess but important in writing destructors. So between Free and Close it comes down to how you want to manage lifetime for your form.

Comment: Always call `Free` instead of `Destroy`. That is its purpose. As for `Close`, that depends on the form.

Answer (score 0):

`Tform.Close`

In VCL closes the form depending on its State. If your `FFormState` is `FSModal` it will do the cancel Action.
If your Form is `MainForm`, the whole apllication will be terminated and so on. For further informations please look into `TCustomForm.Close` inside of `system.pas`.
In the end the Result will be that you dont see the Form anymore, but that does not mean your Reference to the Form is destroyed.

`.free`

free also calls destroy, but like David said it is nil reference safe so in most cases you should use free instead of destroy

`.destroy`

Comment: What is the point of calling FreeAndNil in a form's Destructor, why not just Free?

Comment: That is what TCustomForm.Destroy does! ist Frees the Oject and sets pointer refrence to nil.

Comment: Are you sure about that, @fisi-pjm ? The Destroy destructor does not have access to the pointer reference that was used to call it, so it cannot set it to NIL. That's why there's a FreeAndNIL in the first place.

Comment: I think we talk past each other. TCustomForm is included in VCL.Form. Why should there be accessproblems?

Comment: Which "pointer reference" do you think TCustomForm.Destroy sets to NIL? If I call MyForm.Destroy - what is the value of "MyForm" afterwards? Unchanged or NIL? (The answer is Unchanged).

Comment: a Word of advise, Delete every thing after `.Destroy`

Comment: Destroying a *named* component will set the corresponding reference in the component's `Owner` to nil. A component placed on a Form at design time sets the Form's reference to it during DFM streaming, and clears the reference when it is destroyed.